# How can I lock my own account from remote ssh login with password?

Tags: ssh, authentication, key-authentication

I don't want to disable remote login with password altogether, but I want to make it so that my account is only accessible with key pair authentication (there are other users who wants to use passwords to log in). Is it possible to change this on a per-user basis, ideally without changing system settings?

And to make it clear, my account has sudo access, so I don't want to lock the password.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the Match option in `sshd_config`

> **Match**    Introduces a conditional block.  If all of the criteria on the Match line are satisfied, the keywords on the following lines override those set in the global section of the config file, until either another Match line or the end of the file.[1]

So, *at the end of that file* you could specify:

```
Match User yourusername
PasswordAuthentication no
```

See `man 5 sshd_config` for all of the available options.

[1] http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5

Comment: This is good already, but I want to see if I can do without editing sshd_config.

Comment: Given you are wanting to make a system change, ie., one that _doesn't_ impact on other users, that seems to be unlikely...

Comment: and what about ~/.ssh/config ? Have you tried including the settings there?

Comment: AFAK ~/.ssh/config in for the client, not the server.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer from jasonwryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13873/how-can-i-lock-my-own-account-from-remote-ssh-login-with-password/13874#13874) is going to be the right way to make this change. The only addition I would make is that you could set the match to be group based so that any users in the wheel group would be required to use key authentication while others could use passwords.

I know you want to do this without changing the system config files, but there is a good reason why that will not be possible. In your head it makes sense that your user should be able to institute a more secure login policy, but just because in your mind it is a more secure option doesn't change the fact that it is still a change to the system login requirements for a remote user.

To understand why this is a problem, imagine the scenario the other way around. The system administrator (who can change the system config files) sets the system to key based login only. Then, some user comes along and with only access to their own user file and sets their account to allow password authentication, overriding the system policy. *BEEEEEEP*. Security problem!

Does that explain why the kind of change you want to make is only possible from the system config file?

Comment: It's difficult to think that way around, since if I were a normal user who doesn't sudo, I can happily set up my keys then lock the password, thus making my account "key only authentication".

Comment: In another thought, I could lock my password every time I'm about to log out, which should disallow all password log in for my account. Then once I'm logged in with my keys, I could enable the password again to sudo.  
Obviously it's not a good solution, but it makes me think it's possible.

Comment: You can only do that because the system administrator allowed key authentication and you are only adding restrictions for yourself, not changing anything. Disabling your password just sets it to an invalid value, it doesn't change what authentication the system daemon allows.

Comment: "adding restrictions for yourself, not changing anything", is exactly what I'm wanting to do.

Comment: @Caleb: There would be no security problem in allowing `authorized_keys` to put *more* restrictions, as phunehehe wants. For example `authorized_keys` can restrict certain keys to certain commands.

Comment: @Gilles: Sure, but the general model is for things settable in your user preferences to over-ride system wide preferences. Having a value that you could set in your home folder that would change the system daemon behavior but not actually over-ride the setting would be a documentation and support nightmare. "I change the settings, and X value works but Y is ignored!"

Answer (score 0):

> > Adding restrictions for yourself, not changing anything

Why not at the client side, if it is sure that ssh would be the client to be used for login attempts? If yes, try making changes to ssh_config instead of sshd_config.
Check for parameter 'PasswordAuthentication No' and PreferredAuthentications